# Visual Studio Unit Test Data Path and Source Control

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I have a unit test project for my VB.NET solution that takes a very large data set (multiple Gigabytes). The data set is static, outside of source control (developers unzip a big `.zip` file somewhere on their machine)

I'm trying to figure out how to reference this data set inside my project and I'm having trouble because of the following constraints:

1. The data set may be in a different location on each developer's machine `e:\dev\MySolution\TestProject\` vs. `c:\MySolution\TestProject\data`. We can require it to be in the project folder but I can't require that the project folder be in the same place. This means I can't store the path in source control or I need some way to override it.
2. Because of its size I don't want to have to copy or deploy the test data at runtime because this will slow things down a lot and I don't want to have two copies of it.

My hack-y solution is to use a project property called `DataPath` and reference this inside each test. Then users would just change the property and I'd instruct them not to commit this change.... feels like an anti-pattern though.

My initial thoughts were to somehow store the path in the `project.suo` file which is outside of source control but I can't figure out how to make that work.

Anyone have experience with this?

Comment: you can get local position of source control item, source control directory will be always the same, so you can store that information. Using that you can connect to tfs server get local workspace information, get location of that big file. if you need help leave a comment

Comment: i just read that it is outside source control, then either added to source control, store it on server and have same reference from all machines, or what you plan on doing, or xml config file with all machine names and locations of given file.

Comment: @Claudius I agree. I could require the Data folder to be inside my source folder and then `.gitignore` it. My problem is that the test dll only knows where the build is, not the source. How do you get location of source at runtime?

Comment: if it has very specific name you can search for it. Or get list of files matching and decide based on some other factor. This should help you http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?727253-VB-NET-Search-directories-subdirectories-for-files-excluding-files-by-name-or-ext

Comment: @Claudius it's a good suggestion but it's not going to work for me. I can't guarantee that the file I find is the one I want just searching for it since there may be lots of different but similar files lying around.

Comment: similar with name, size, extension?

Comment: Yeah. Identical actually. It's an ESRI Geodatabase and there may be thousands with similar names, sizes etc just lying around.

Comment: Then user can pick it, or you can look up source in tfs, get local path and thats where it is?

Comment: tfs? Ideally I'd like to require it be in a subdirectory of the .NET source but I don't know how to find that path at runtime.